# string with StingBuilder error c#

Tags: c#, html, string, stringbuilder

i am trying to create a string with html code to use it to render a cart

```
for(var i=1; i<=@totalCountItems; i++){

                            sb.Append("<div class=\"ibox-content\">"+
                                        "<div class=\"table-responsive\">"+
                                            "<table class=\"table shoping-cart-table\">"+
                                                "<tbody>"+
                                                    "<tr>"+
                                                        "<td width=\"90\">"+
                                                            "<div class=\"cart-product-imitation\">"+
                                                            "</div>"+
                                                        "</td>"+
                                                        "<td class=\"desc\">"+
                                                            "<h3>"+
                                                                "<a href=\"#\" class=\"text-navy\">"+
                                                                    Model[i].Name+
                                                                "</a>"+
                                                            "</h3>"+
                                                            "<p class=\"small\">"+
                                                                Model[i].DescriptionLong+
                                                            "</p>"+
                                                            "<dl class=\"small m-b-none\">"+
                                                                "<dt>Description lists</dt>"+
                                                                "<dd>"+Model[i].DescriptionSort+"</dd>"+
                                                            "</dl>"+
                                                            "<div class=\"m-t-sm\">"+
                                                                "<a href=\"#\" class=\"text-muted\"><i class=\"fa fa-gift\"></i> Add gift package</a>"+
                                                                "|"+
                                                                "<a href=\"#\" class=\"text-muted\"><i class=\"fa fa-trash\"></i> Remove item</a>"+
                                                            "</div>"+
                                                        "</td>"+
                                                        "<td>"+
                                                            "$"+Model[i].Price+
                                                            "<s class=\"small text-muted\">$"+Model[i].DPrice+"</s>"+
                                                        "</td>"+
                                                        "<td width=\"65\">"+
                                                            "<input type=\"text\" class=\"form-control\" placeholder=\"1\">"+
                                                        "</td>"+
                                                        "<td>"+
                                                            "<h4>"+
                                                                "$"+(Model[i].Price)*(@Model[i].Count)+
                                                            "</h4>"+
                                                        "</td>"+
                                                    "</tr>"+
                                            "</tbody>"+
                                        "</table>"+
                                    "</div>"+
                            "</div>");
                        }}
                    $("iboxTest").html(@sb);
                }
```

the second time inside the loop  i am getting an error 'System.OutOfMemoryException' in mscorlib.dll
i reduced the size of the string and it worked. any ideas?

Comment: My idea: string value is too big? If need to use such a bunch of memory space for holding a string, something in your architecture is definitely wrong.

Comment: What you're doing is quite dangerous. You should try to create something like a partial view which will act like a template for your cart.

Comment: Take a look at display templates.

Answer (score 2):

You use `StringBuilder`, but you also create too many strings.

Doing this:

```
sb.Append("<div class=\"ibox-content\">"+
   "<div class=\"table-responsive\">"+
       "<table class=\"table shoping-cart-table\">"+
          ......
```

you append only one time, but using `+` (concatenation) you creates many new strings and get `OutOfMemoryException`.

Code above should be changed to something like this(append every line using `StringBuilder.Append()`):

```
sb.Append("<div class=\"ibox-content\">");
sb.Append("<div class=\"table-responsive\">");
sb.Append("<table class=\"table shoping-cart-table\">");
...
```

Comment: Using a StringBuilder for this is just terrible.

Comment: @OwenPauling, Thanks, I agree with you, but the question is why is there `OutOfMemoryException`.

Comment: `+`  is replaced with `string.Concat` at compile time (of course only when it is possible) which is much better than `+` (no reckless memory allocation). I'd preffer to use `+` instead of `Append` when `+` count is exactly known (like in this case, concatenation in `Append` param). I think that problem is `for` loop that appends many many times to string builder which is limited by memory.